# What would cause this different outcome in this POST request in Postman vs. Async request?

Tags: php, postman

I have been testing out an app that I created with a PHP backend and I have ran into something that was a bit confusing to me.

I kept running into errors with POSTMAN when I would try and run this POST request to my server.

Could this be because I am not setting the correct `content-type` header in POSTMAN like I do in my apps http request?

Here is a look at my POST code from my backend:

```
 /**
 *  Get POST parameter
 *
 * @param String $key
 * @return string
 */
public function post(String $key = '') {
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata, true);

    if ($key != '') {
        return isset($request[$key]) ? $this->clean($request[$key]) : null;
    } 

    return ($request);
}
```

If I change the code to this:

```
/**
 *  Get $_POST parameter
 *
 * @param String $key
 * @return string
 */
public function post(String $key = '') {

    if ($key != '')
        return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $this->clean($_POST[$key]) : null;

    return  $this->clean($_POST);
}
```

Then it works perfectly in POSTMAN, but does not work in my app's http request.

Any thoughts on what I have set-up incorrectly that is causing this?

Comment: Perhaps this: https://www.php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php ("php://input is **not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"**.") _Guessing here._

Comment: For debug reasons you should f.e. use the `$_POST` variant and check what you get f.e. using `file_put_contents('your/file.log', var_export($_POST, true))`

Comment: Your application is sending data in raw format, probably using json format and application/json;charset=UTF-8 content-type. Your postman request is probably configured with form-data body. If you want to simulate your application behaviour in Postman, try to use boby -> raw and insert a json formatted body.

Comment: `because I am not setting the correct content-type header `...that, plus actually sending the content in a different format, potentially. Content-type simply tells the server what kind of content to expect...it doesn't magically convert the content as well - that's your job.